# R shiny app cannot find local loaded data. Why?

Tags: r, shiny

I am new to R shiny, and got some issues regarding loading data.

In my `server.R`, I have some code to source R utility functions and R data. I put the data files in a subdirectory `data` under the shiny app.

```
source("utilities.R")
load("data/mydata.RData")
```

The structure of my `shinyServer` looks like following:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  ## ...

  ## I have a action Button, Run, to start model fitting
  main_plot <- eventReactive(input$run, {

    fit <- main.shiny()

    post_analysis_shiny(fit = fit)

  })

  main.shiny <- function() {
    ## get input, fit model
    ## main.fit() is a function in utilities.R, which requires data saved in mydata.RData
    fit <- main.fit()

    fit

  }

})
```

When I Run App, shiny cannot find the data. But if I manually load the data before I run shiny, everything works fine. What is the problem here? Thank you very much.

Comment: Not directly a solution, but you can create a `global.R` file in addition to `UI.R` and `server.R` including the loading or transformation of the data.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you are using Rstudio.

When you load and source "manually" in you R Rstudio session, data and functions are avaialble to shiny.

Otherwise to add on Jimbou answer : 
You should have in your shiny folder :

```
shinyappp
--- global.R
--- ui.R
--- server.R
--- utilisties.R
--- data
```

In global.R : you have :

```
 source("utilities.R")
 load("data/mydata.RData")
```